# Modal window binding data -Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can someone tell me why the data in the scope is not getting passed to the controller.

Click on the Open Me . Add some text inside the modal window .Click Ok.
why empty items are getting added?

see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S0zQspeydOmjTyMxZw0k?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following binding instead:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="$parent.currentcommitment"></textarea>
```

Comment: it worked ! but tell me why i need to use $parent here .currentcommitment is defined within the same controller's scope right ?

Comment: $modal creates specific transclusion scope for its modals. So you have one more scope between template and controller. This is why $parent helps. Also you can use ng-model="currentcommitment.text" and $scope.currentcommitment = { text: "" }. Read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes for more info.